# WebStorm - Change the color of the squiggly lines

Tags: webstorm

I'm a newbie to WebStorm and I noticed when I'm coding in JavaScript there are grey squiggly lines for errors/undefined variables however they are not very noticeable.

I wanted to change the color of the squiggly lines to red however I'm unable to find the setting to do this. Does anyone know where to go to change this?

Comment: I too couldn't find this setting, for whatever odd reason. Within PyCharm I was assuming it was related specifically to a PEP 8 color setting. It's not. Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`

The rest depends on severity of the "error" -- if it's an Error, Warning, Weak Warning etc. Based on your description it most likely a Warning or Weak Warning.

You need to find that particular style in the list and modify the **Effects** colour/style:

[image]

---

**EDIT: 2022-05-24**

Modern IDE versions have a slightly different structure but overall it is still the same:

- `Colors & Fonts` section is now called `Color Scheme`
- Appropriate styles are now grouped under the "Errors and Warnings" node.

`Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General`

[image]

Comment: Thanks i have been looking for this setting for a while!